# Is it possible to join these tables a view and combined columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, view

I currently have a few tables that look like this:

```
create table Actors
(ActorID    varchar (20) primary key not null,
FirstName   varchar (35) null,
LastName    varchar(35) null,
"Address"   varchar (30) null,
Country varchar (30) null,
"State/Province"    varchar (30) null,
PhoneNumber varchar (15)  null
);
```

go

```
    insert into Actors
    values ('A-63','Tom','Hanks','4332 Whalibee Way','US','Washington','555-619-9905') ,
    ('A-42','Sandra','Bullock','63 Sharridon Ave.','US','Texas','329-556-3030');
go

create table Director
    (   DirectorID  varchar (20) primary key not null,
    FirstName   varchar (40) null,
    LastName    varchar(40) null,
    MovieID varchar(20) foreign key references Movies (MovieID) null,
    "Address" varchar ( 30) null,
    Country varchar (35) null,
    "State/Province"    varchar (35) null,
    PhoneNumber     varchar (15) null
    );
go

    insert into Director values
    ('D700','David','Speilberg','MO-57','9000 Cheque St','US','California','432-553-2267'),
    ('D-900','William','Bruckheimner','MO-31','68585 lava lane','US','California','519-242-2543');
go

create table Producer
    (ProducerID     varchar (20) primary key not null,  
    FirstName   varchar (40) null,
    LastName    varchar (40) null,
    MovieID varchar (20) foreign key references Movies(MovieID) null,
    "Address"   varchar (30) null,
    Country varchar (35) null,
    "State/Province"    varchar (35) null,
    PhoneNumber varchar (15) null
    );
    go

    insert into producer values 
    ('P-123','RJ','Abrams','MO-57','45 Canterbelly Cres.','US','California','556-876-4134'),
    ('P-82','Malcolm','Brooks','MO-62','678 Undertree rd','US','Arizona','897-332-6633');
go

Create table Movies 
( MovieID varchar(20) primary key not null,
    MovieName   varchar (40) null ,
    "Type"  varchar (20) null,
    Rating  varchar (20) null,
    Director    varchar (35) null,
    Producer    varchar (35) null,
    MainActor1  varchar (35) null,
    MainActor2  varchar (35) null,
    SupportingActor1    varchar (35) null,
    SupportingActor2    varchar (35) null,
    ReleaseDate Date null,
    Description varchar(500) null
    );
    go

    Insert into Movies (MovieID,MovieName,"Type",Rating,Director,Producer,MainActor1,MainActor2,SupportingActor1,SupportingActor2,ReleaseDate,"Description")
    values ( 'MO-150','The Legend Of Zelda','Fantasy','R','','','','','','','July 23 2018',''),
    (   'MO-216','The SQL Games:Replication','Science Fiction','PG','','','','','None','','March 20 2020','');
go
```

current Format: Robert  Downey JR.
FirstName| LastName
Ben        Affleck
Christian    Bale
Will         Smith
Charlize     Theron
Angelina     Jolie
Jessica      Alba
Cameron     Diaz
Jennifer    Anniston
Bradley     Cooper
Sandra       Bullock
Leonardo    DiCaprio
Matt        Damon
Chris        Hemsworth
Tom         Hanks
Mila      Kunis
Scarlet   Johansson
Emma      Stone
Julia     Roberts

Now I have a Table for Actors, Directors and Producers as well as a Movie table, all with their own ID columns and a MovieInfo table with foreign keys to link them.

I was wondering if there was a way to make a view that would take the first and last names and put them together in 1 column for the Actors,Producers,Directors and Movies column and have them joined.

So the table would look like this:

Actors(col1)   Producers(col2)   Directors (col3) Movies(col4)
 (Sandra Bullock) (RJ Abrams)   (David Speilberg) (Late For Class)

Any help is greatly appreciated. I know if it was possible to do a view as such, it'd probably be very complicated.

Comment: What should happen when the movie has more than one producer or Director.. Sample data and expected output would help

Answer (score 1):

You can join the values of two columns by using the || operator.

```
SELECT FirstName || ' ' || LastName as name FROM Actors
```

would return a single column called "name" that contains the Actors FirstName and LastName columns concatenated together.  Just use that same logic for all of the tables, joined appropriately of course.

Comment: Does not like the || in the field.